# Sharepoint Search Engine

Tags: search

How do we customize our search engine/results so it's only searching for documents we've uploaded (ideally only searching for words within titles and enterprise keywords). Our search engine currently searches everything within SharePoint, even pulling up web pages as results - it's creating a mess and makes it difficult for users to find specific files.

Our intranet is hosted on Sharepoint 2013

Comment: you can use the result source to configure the search....check this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx